# Terminology of the Traversable concept

Tags: haskell, category-theory, traversable

Why are we calling a flip of structure a "sequence" and why are we talking about "traverse" and "Traversal" ?

I'm adding the implementation in haskell of these concepts as a matter to discussion...

```
class (Functor t, Foldable t) => Traversable t where
    {-# MINIMAL traverse | sequenceA #-}

    -- | Map each element of a structure to an action, evaluate these actions
    -- from left to right, and collect the results. For a version that ignores
    -- the results see 'Data.Foldable.traverse_'.
    traverse :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
    traverse f = sequenceA . fmap f

    -- | Evaluate each action in the structure from left to right, and
    -- and collect the results. For a version that ignores the results
    -- see 'Data.Foldable.sequenceA_'.
    sequenceA :: Applicative f => t (f a) -> f (t a)
    sequenceA = traverse id
```

Comment: `sequence` (verb): turn a sequence (noun) of applicative "actions"  "inside" a traversable "container" into one applicative "action" producing the sequence of results. For lists, it can be defined as `sequenceA = foldr (liftA2 (:)) (pure [])`. `traverse` could be called `mapA` since it's parallel to `mapM`. I guess mapping is kind of a traversing.

Comment: also, for lists again, `sequence [] = return [] ; sequence (x:xs) = do { x <- x; xs <- sequence xs; return (x:xs) }` where all "computations" `xs` are known in advance, so full power of Monad's being able to create new computations based on results of previously-run computations (as in `y <- foo x`) is actually *not* needed. Hence the Applicative Functor, a less powerful, more general Functor than Monadic Functor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's begin by considering `fmap`:

```
fmap :: Functor t => (a -> b) -> t a -> t b
```

We can describe what it does as finding all `a` values in a `t a` and applying a function to them. Note that, infinite structure shenanigans aside, the order in which the implementation of `fmap` reaches the `a` values to modify them doesn't matter as far as the final result is concerned.

Now let's have a look at `traverse`:

```
traverse :: (Applicative f, Traversable t) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
```

Like `fmap`, `traverse` also involves applying a function to values found in a structure (it's no wonder `traverse`'s forerunner was called `mapM`). `traverse`, however, also produces applicative effects for each of the `a` values (the `f` in `a -> f b`), and it involves combining those effects in some order to get the overall `f (t b)` result. In general (i.e. as long as `f` isn't a commutative applicative, such as `Maybe`), the order of effects affects the result. That being so, any `Traversable` instance corresponds to a specific order in which the values in the structure will be visited. The name "traverse" (that is, as Will Ness points out, "travel across or through") is meant to convey this sense of direction.

On a related note, `traverse` can be decomposed into a plain mapping which produces effects followed by the sequencing of those effects...

```
sequenceA :: (Applicative f, Traversable t) => t (f a) -> f (t a)

traverse f = sequenceA . fmap f
sequenceA = traverse id
```

... ergo the "sequence" name.

It is also worth emphasising that `traverse` does capture various ways of going through a structure and doing things at each stop (cf. `for` being the name for `flip traverse`). In particular, we recover `fmap` by picking `Identity` as the Applicative functor (i.e. by not actually generating any effects), and `foldMap` (that is, list-like folding) by picking `Monoid m => Const m` instead. Things we *can't* do with `traverse` include dropping, duplicating or rearranging elements -- it doesn't allow tearing down a data structure in arbitrary ways like a general fold/catamorphism does. With `traverse`, we can move through a `Traversable` structure, but we can't reshape it.

Comment: Thanks @duplode !

Comment: @NicolasHenin You are welcome. Something I forgot to mention: the most popular name in Haskell for the dual "flip of a structure" is [`distribute :: (Functor f, Distributive g) => f (g a) -> g (f a)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributive-0.5.3/docs/Data-Distributive.html). (Then again, one of the key papers about `Traversable` uses `dist` as a name for `sequenceA`, which, I guess, only shows how hard it can be to name things.)

Answer (score 3):

It's "*to* sequence", not "a". I.e. ["Arrange in a particular order"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sequence), here from left to right. And it is a generalization of [`sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.0.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:sequence) (note the old `base` version), which may make the name more obvious.

Comment: ok cool, it makes sense .. and then why traverse / traversal ?

Comment: That's much harder for me to say. Try to look at the papers linked in http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html?

Comment: "traverse" is straightforward English: "travel across or through". i.e. enumerate in some kind of linear fashion all elements `a` inside a container `t a`. like enumerating nodes in a binary tree. or enumerating [a tree's fringe](http://www.dreamsongs.com/10ideas.html).

Comment: What I dislike a bit is that `sequenceA` seems more basic (just look at the descriptions), but the class is still named for `traverse` :)